# Getting unique information from .CSV, group and average

Tags: matlab, csv, unique

I have this .CSV file (attached - link) where I need to group and compute the average value from the information from the first column. Precisely, I need to group all 08T into one group, 07T into one group, etc (05T, 04T), and compute the average from the third column using Matlab.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qk355wx07fejzz5/Test_Data.csv?dl=0

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you want `splitapply()` and `findgroups()`.

Comment: Hi Andrew thanks, I will go through both functions.

Comment: Hi Andrew could you please provide me some direction to proceed, thanks.